# ReactiveUI - why is simple ReactiveList.Changed -> ToProperty not working?

Tags: c#, mvvm, system.reactive, observable, reactiveui

I tried many different modifications but nothing helps. When I dig into sources it's a bunch of deep magic involving static state like `ConditionalWeakTable` etc.

```
private readonly ReactiveList<Item> _list = new ReactiveList<Item>();

private decimal _sum;
public decimal Sum
{
    get { return _sum; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _sum, value); }
}

_list
    .Changed
    .Select(_ => _list.Select(i => i.Value).Sum())
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Sum)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your approach (in the question) is that you are not using the returned value from `.ToProperty()` call, which is `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` class. The returned value is simply ignored.

RxUI is actually simple when it comes to code around properties. They are simply a boilerplate which you should never modify significantly. In your case, you want to use an *output property* pattern, described [here in the docs](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/oaph/). Adapted to your example, you don't need a setter with `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`. Instead, you should use something like this:

```
private readonly ReactiveList<Item> _list = new ReactiveList<Item>();

private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<decimal> _sum;
public decimal Sum {
    get { return _sum.Value; }
}

// in constructor
_sum = _list
    .Changed
    .Select(_ => _list.Select(i => i.Value).Sum())
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Sum);
```

As you already noticed, `ToProperty` has an overload accepting an output reference to an `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` field in your ViewModel, which you can use (like in your answer). In the end, the overload you choose is a matter of style/taste. The below does exactly the same as above piece of code:

```
// in constructor, alternatively
_list
    .Changed
    .Select(_ => _list.Select(i => i.Value).Sum())
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Sum, out _sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't know why on earth there are other overloads, but this one works:

```
private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<decimal> _sum;

...
.ToProperty(this, x => x.Sum, out _sum));


public decimal Sum => _sum.Value;
```